# XAMPP mysql relative path to xmapp folder

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am having issues with setting up mysql config file for relative paths, therefore I editted the my.ini file.

**Static paths work perfectly:**
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"

**Relative paths aren't (root folder should be xampp I guess):**
tmpdir = "tmp" 
datadir = "data"

I cannot imagine that there is no way to achieve relative paths to the project.

Comment: Why would one want to do that? There usually is exactly one mysql server on a system, everything else makes zero sense (with the exception of containers). So a system wide, so absolute path surely does make more sense.

Comment: The purpose I want to use relative paths is: If i move the complete xampp folder, I dont want to adjust the config files every single time. The project will be shared on several PCs, not necessarily the same folder location :(.

Comment: It is more than questionable to move a native xampp installation to perform a software rollout. Either use containers (docker or similar) or some installation routine that is able to adapt the initial data to the found environment.

Comment: As far as i know, docker are bound to unix systems, i am working with windows. I think we are going away from the original issue. Can't you somehow make MySQL paths relative?

Comment: Apart from that I wrote "or similar" you should note that the docker technology can very well be used on MS-Windows based systems.

Comment: Coming back to your question: I _doubt_ that a relative path is accepted in the configuration. I gave the reason in the start. How should a relative path be interpreted? Relative to what? Relative paths are usually interpreted relative to a _running process_, but which one is that for a daemon to be started at system startup? But as said: I doubt it. I might very well be mistaken in that.

Comment: Hm if you start mysql XAMPP uses a command which itself is relative, there it starts the SQL server on a relative basis, reading out the config file my.ini. I just cant understand why they dont offer the option for relative paths... here the statement XAMPP uses for starting the SQL server
mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that but always start your mysqld server manually (not automatically by windows service) to make sure the current directory.

From the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html